# How to solve $x^x+1=y^2$ in positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> For integers $x, y>0$ solve the following Equation:
>   $$x^x+1=y^2$$

Well, $x$ must be odd. Because for $x=2z$ we get difference of two squares as $1$, which is impossible in positive integers. We have $$x^x=(y-1)(y+1).$$ Thus for every prime divisor of $x$ like $p$, if $v_p(x)=k$, then $y=p^{kx}z \pm 1$. Where $\gcd(p, z)=1$. I am not sure how to use this! Any ideas?

**Edit:** Mihăilescu's theorem will do this easily. I am interested in an alternative elementary method. If you can think of one please let me know.

Comment: C a t a l a n .

Comment: K i l l e d  i t !

Comment: If $x$ is odd, $y$ is even and so $y-1,y+1$ are relatively prime, hence must both be $x$th powers...

Comment: And if $1=y^2-(2u)^{2u}=(y-(2u)^u)(y+(2u)^u)$....

Comment: @Wojowu very good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can immediately exclude $x=1$ and $x=0$ , the latter because it is standard that $0^0=1$ is assumed.

---

Assume $x=2w$ being even. Then we get
$$ y^2 - (2w)^{2w}= 1 \\
  (y-x^w)(y+x^w) = 1 \\
\to x^w=(2w)^w =0,y=1 
$$
There is no $w$ allowing $(2w)^w=0$ , thus no solution. The same answer that you've already found.

---

Now assume $x=2w+1$ being odd. We rewrite
$$ x^x = y^2-1 = (y-1)(y+1)$$

- Assume $y=2z$ being **even**. Then $x^x$ must have two coprime odd factors, so $x=pq$
  Then $$ (y-1)(y+1)=(pq)^x = p^x q^x $$ and we might assume $y-1 = p^x$ and $y+1 = q^x$. But then $q^x-p^x=2$ but which is impossible for two different odd numbers $p,q,x \gt 1$ because $q^x-p^x = (q-p){ q^x-p^x\over q-p}$  and one factor must equal $1$ and the other must equal $2$.
- Assume $y=2z+1$ being **odd** giving $ x^x = y^2-1 = 2z(2z+2)=8{z(z+1)\over 2}$. 
  But the rhs being even means $x$ must be even. But this has already been handled above.

So none of the possible conditions on $x$ and $y$ allow a solution.